# bottom bar with multi colored icons

Tags: android, bottombar

not sure this is possible, checked around but not found anything. 
In IOS this is possible , below the facebook bottombarview as seen in iphone

[image]

what about android?

Comment: Change the drawable icon to selected drawable icon when item is selected from bottombar

Comment: Read the question please. "multi colored"